# Xubuntu browser and camera security

Tags: security

I get spam emails that claim that my browser has functioned as a keylogger and that my camera has been recording. Is this possible in Xubuntu without root access?

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible**, you don't need root for that.

For example:

- Someone with physical access
- Someone within your local network when you have open ports (e.g. port `22` = `ssh`) and use weak passwords.
- If you have open ports and forward them to your computer and use weak passwords.
- You installed software from a bad source (malware).
- You use outdated software that accesses the internet.

**But ...** I think in your case it is quite unlikely.
I would say, if these guys really had access, they would send proof.